# Java web service frameworks

Tags: java, web-services

This is my first time with Web services. I have to develop web services in java which should be having good WS-* standards, should loosely-coupled, scalable, highly secure, fast response time. I know I've to consider trade-offs. I have checked on some frameworks like Axis2, CXF, Spring WS. Please share your experiences and views on these frameworks and other frameworks, which will help me in deciding which one to go to.

Comment: Do you need to develop a Web Service server, or client?

Comment: Actually both. I require to create some web services which apart from doing stuff will call another web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also recommend taking a look at [JAX-WS 2.0](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224). It is also easy to use with very little configuration and annotations. Mark Hansen's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130449687) does a good job explaining SOA using jax-ws.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Spring user, so I'm doing it with Spring WS 1.5.5.  Very nice, especially using annotations.

Answer (score 1):

I found axis2 a bit cumbersome (try google on "axis2 problems") luckily my organization has decided to go with the REST approach instead of WS-*.

Answer (score 1):

[Metro](https://metro.java.net/) is the JAX-WS reference implementation with support for various WS-* specification. I find it easy to understand and use. It provides interoperability with the Microsoft .NET WCF stack and integration with Spring, Netbeans, Maven2 and ant.

Metro is fully supported on [Glassfish](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/) and both can be installed together easily with the latest [Glassfish v3 prelude](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/downloads/v3-prelude.html) (commercial support [available](http://www.sun.com/software/products/glassfishv3_prelude/support.xml) from Sun).

The Metro's homepage reference a [web services stack comparison](http://wiki.apache.org/ws/StackComparison) at the Apache WS Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like CXF because it's very easy to setup and it performs very well. I also, agree with "LiorH" and don't like Axis2.
However, the only article I could find for you to do a comparison was this one.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jws14/index.html

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Because you mention scalability and performances in your requirements, I assume that there will be some application server involved. In this case, you should go with the WebServices framework that comes bundled with the application server to avoid incompatibility problems between the WebServices framework of the app server and the one you would pick up (ClassCastExceptions, MethodNotFound, etc).